# Ошибка при запуске сервера на react js

Tags: reactjs, npm

Создал приложение - create-react-app app. Запустил - npm start.
Ошибка:

```
**events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)     
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todo-list@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todo-list@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Алекс\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-13T12_14_12_199Z-debug.log**
```

Comment: а npm install был?

Comment: нет, я сразу запустил проект

Comment: так попробуйте сделать

Comment: сделал npm install, все равно ошибка

Comment: а так делали npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

Comment: каталог меняли?

Comment: я сразу все писал там

Comment: Я обычно бывало удалял node_modules и package-lock, потом npm install и помогало

Comment: не, не помогло...

Answer (score 2):

добавил переменную в среду пользователя PATH - `C:\Windows\System32`